# java- using Commit Transaction to insert to table

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I want to start a transaction in my java program to insert into my table in MYSQL.

My code:

```
 public void index(String path) throws Exception {   

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");


                    String sql="insert IGNORE into  test.indextable values (?,?);";

                       preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
                     int i=0;
                    for (String word : words) {

                        // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                        // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
                    // insert every word directly to table db
                      word=word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
                        preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
                        preparedStatement.setString(2, word);

                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.print("Add ");



                }


            }

        con.connect().commit();
        preparedStatement.close();
     con.connect().close();

        System.out.println("Successfully commited changes to the database!");
```

I set `AutoCommit` to false in my connection class.
However when I run the program, it usually prints out the message " Add" a couple of times before it stops there. If I keep waiting it eventually says: `Lock Time Exceeding,please restart transaction`.

EDIT:

Connection method(in a different class):

```
public Connection connect() throws Exception {
    Properties props=new Properties();


    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");

    props.load(in);
    in.close();



    String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
    if(driver!=null){
        Class.forName(driver);

    }

    String url=props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    String username=props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    String password=props.getProperty("jdbc.password");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    //con.setAutoCommit(false);

    return con;

}
```

Rollback function:

```
 public void rollbackEntries() throws Exception {

       con.connect().rollback();
       System.out.println("Successfully rolled back changes from the database!");


    }
```

Comment: Show `con.connect()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use same connection for commit

```
 Connection con =con.connect();
 ....
 con.commit();
 con.close();
```

As aside notes, move to connection pool and catch exceptions to release resources also in case of an error

Comment: Where do i put this statement?

Comment: @Daredevil in index method instead of using new connection with `con.connect()`

Comment: @Daredevil Normally yes, to commit when finish, but how much records are you adding? if more than thousands consider executing a batch

Comment: Basically, it reads a file, extracts the words from the file, it depends on how many words in the file which represents the records. Then it adds to the table. The concern is if there is something wrong during adding to the table for the file, then I need to rollback, which is why I need to perform a transaction

Comment: Hey it kinda works but how do I test it out to make sure it's not fully commited?

Comment: @Daredevil select records from your DB

Comment: But I realize my table is not updating the Status To Complete anymore, it was updating before this from another method

Comment: @Daredevil I think you should ask a new question